# Read Data from Excel is not working, not reading data to my application, I have shared my public repository.please have a look

Tags: selenium, apache-poi

I am trying to read Data from Excel file and input data to my web application but its not working.

Please have a look at my code.This is the class created for excel

I used Apache POI

**Excel class**

```java
package ReadExcel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class Excel_Data {
    HSSFWorkbook  wb;
    HSSFSheet sheet1;
    public Excel_Data(String fileName,String sheetName) throws Exception {
        File src= new File("E:\\Jino_testing\\Git_Hub\\Zmarta_se\\resources\\Zmarta.xls");
        FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    }

    public  String getData( int  sheetNumber, int row,int column) { 
        HSSFSheet sheet1 =wb.getSheetAt(0);
        String data =sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();
        return  data;
    }
}
```

This is my Test class which I am running

```java
public void ApplyLoan() throws Exception {
     //Reading Excel  
     Excel_Data read = new  Excel_Data("Zmarta.xls","Co-Applicant" );
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     driver.findElement(apply).click();
     driver.findElement(loan).click();
     Thread.sleep(7000);
     driver.findElement(amount).sendKeys(read.getData(0,1,1));
     Thread.sleep(3000);
     new Select (driver.findElement(years)).selectByVisibleText("14 år");
 }
```

Comment: What does "not working" means? Any errors? Which? Where? Btw.: You are declaring class members `HSSFWorkbook  wb` and `HSSFSheet sheet1` but don't using them but do new declaring them in the methods.

Comment: @AxelRichter Not working means not reading data  ERROR--ava.lang.NullPointerException
 at ReadExcel.Excel_Data.getData(Excel_Data.java:41)
 at Pageobject.Locators.ApplyLoan(Locators.java:138)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: As said, you should using your declared class members. So `HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);` should be `this.wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);` in `Excel_Data` constructor. Else `wb` is `NULL` in `getData` method.

Comment: @jino There are various errors in your code...share complete code so that I can update it.

Comment: @GauravGenius  You can find in my  repo  https://github.com/jino555

Comment: @GauravGenius Thanks Bro, it worked, will need your help in future also

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @GauravGenius Iam getting an error                            """java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell""""                                                                                                Also if possible can u explaoin the code in Excel_data class

Comment: @GauravGenius   Is there any simple code for reading excel data and also Iam getting error on method getRawValue();

Comment: @GauravGenius  I tried to read next sheet and I used  "1" for next sheet driver.findElement(cossn).sendKeys(read.getData(1, 2, 2)); but its not reading.what can be the reason

Comment: @jino is there any error? paste it here

Comment: @GauravGenius No Gaurav there is no error showing . Can u please have a look into my code   Repo->   github.com/jino555

Comment: @jino I can see in your repo... `driver.findElement(cossn).sendKeys(read.getData(0, 2, 2));` this call is for sheet at 0 index. modify it with `driver.findElement(cossn).sendKeys(read.getData(1, 2, 2));` and make sure there is some data in corresponding row, colum

Comment: @GauravGenius soory i forgot to update  the code in github , i added sheetindex as 1 but not working

Comment: @jino print value returned by function `System.out.println(read.getData(1, 2, 2))` verify whether it is blank, if it is blank check sheet(1) in your excel file whether it contains data @row(2) column(2)

Comment: @GauravGenius i checked it coming blank and data is available in sheet(2) row(2) column(2)

Comment: @GauravGenius U can find my excel sheet in resources folder in github

Comment: @jino ..I've gone through your excel sheet...in sheet there is only one cell which has data which is @ 0th row, 5th column, contains `ssn`. which I can successfully print with `System.out.println(read.getData(1, 0, 5));` So basically `System.out.println(read.getData(1, 2, 2));` cell is blank that's why it is printing blank.

Comment: @GauravGenius thanks its working, This is a client project , Whats your opinion on the code , Is it  a standard one ,any suggestions or improvments

Comment: @jino ..welcome..one thing you can improve..put locators in separate file i.e. `Keyword Driven` approach to make your code more readable...If resolution helped, you can accept my answer !

Comment: @GauravGenius Thanks Ok , I will try with keyword drivem ( storing all locators in a separate file) Now, i have used POM Concept , created a separte class "Locators" for strong all locators and methods of it and a base class for calling that methods.....so using POM Concept is a standard one or not?

Comment: @jino yes it is a standard..by the way accept my answer so that other users can trust it

Comment: @GauravGenius yes sure , i will use it

Comment: @GauravGenius donee

Comment: @jino I can't see answer accepted checkbox, have you really accepted?

Comment: @GauravGenius i have done already,please check it

Comment: @GauravGenius  Hi Gaurav, have a doubt, Can we call 2 separate classes in a single class by creating object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various errors in your code, here is the corrected code...

**Here is your `Excel_Data` class**

```
public class Excel_Data {
    HSSFWorkbook  wb;
    HSSFSheet sheet1;
    HSSFCell cell;

    public Excel_Data(String fileName) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    }

    public  String getData(int sheetNumber, int row, int column) { 

        sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
        String data = "";
        try{
            cell = sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column);
            switch(cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
                case BOOLEAN:
                    data = cell.getRawValue();
                    break;
                case NUMERIC:
                    data = cell.getRawValue();
                    break;
                case STRING:
                    data = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

**Here is `Test` class**

```
public void ApplyLoan() throws Exception {
    //Reading Excel  
    Excel_Data read = new Excel_Data("E:\\Jino_testing\\Git_Hub\\Zmarta_se\\resources\\Zmarta.xls");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(apply).click();
    driver.findElement(loan).click();
    Thread.sleep(7000);
    driver.findElement(amount).sendKeys(read.getData(0,1,1));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    new Select (driver.findElement(years)).selectByVisibleText("14 år");
}
```

**Note ->** `HSSFWorkbook` is to read from `.xls` file... use `XSSFWorkbook` to read from `.xlsx` file.

Comment: @jino, You need to specify which type of data you are going to read from cell. Editing my answer

Comment: @jino, follow changes in undated answer

Comment: @jino, this is very simple code to read excel data, logically to read from excel, you have to input excel file name, then you have to find workbook, then you have to go to cell to read actual data, which could be of various data types...that's all there in code nothing else...so it's simple. Further if you can use single function instead of two...and if you want to invoke test for each rown in excel, you can use `@DataProvider` testNG class.

Comment: Gaurav ...Iam getting error on method getRawValue(); –

Comment: @jino, see my answer to  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683878/how-to-read-a-numeric-value-i-e-double-value-from-excel-sheet-using-apache-po/48693334#48693334)..this include complete script to read data from excel sheet with `@DataProvider` testNG.